# How developer can force an application to move to sd card

Tags: android

I am doing a Android application. When the users download the application, i want the application to be installed in sd card. Can i set any permission in manifest from the developer side so that when the user download the application, it either move automatically to sd card or ask the user for permission to move the app to sd card.Any suggestion in this case is helpful and highly appreciable

Thanks inAdvance

Comment: Have You tried http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

Youc an add thjis in your manifest.You will having more options.This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) will help you.

Comment: Any time am happy helping :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can set `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` in AndroidManifest.xml.

Check Android documentation for [this attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install).

> "preferExternal" => The application prefers to be installed on the
>   external storage (SD card). There is no guarantee that the system will
>   honor this request. The application might be installed on internal
>   storage if the external media is unavailable or full, or if the
>   application uses the forward-locking mechanism (not supported on
>   external storage). Once installed, the user can move the application
>   to either internal or external storage through the system settings.

Answer (score 1):

`android:installLocation="preferExternal"` in AndroidManifest.xml.
Try this it successfully worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="string"
            android:sharedUserId="string"
            android:sharedUserLabel="string resource" 
            android:versionCode="integer"
            android:versionName="string"
            android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"] >
. . </manifest>
```

use preferExternal to move to sdcard
Here there are other options also for future use..